# How to create an alias for standard "java" execution command?

Tags: linux, bash, java, command-line-arguments

I want to create an alias for running the java projects on command line, like instead of putting "java classname" every time ; I want to create an alias for that 'java' command. For instance, "run classname". Is there any way to substitute standard java project execution command with our own? Thank You.

Comment: Cross-posted on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775019/how-to-create-an-alias-for-standard-java-execution-command

Comment: Are you trying to be able to just run a Java class without specifying "java" at all, as in load `myclass.class` into the Java runtime just by typing `./myclass`? I don't know a way to do that. If you simply want to be able to add parameters to (or make an alternate name for) the `java` command, you can simply use `alias` like for any other command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alias for executing a specific class (with specific parameters) add the following to your bash profile file (something like .bash or .profile in your home directory):

```
alias aliasname="java classname param1 param2"
```

This would run the class indicated by classname with the parameters specified when you type aliasname in your command line.

However, if you want an alias that can take any class (and any parameter) add the following the your bash profile:

```
function functionname() { java $@ }
```

Which is like renaming the java command to functionname without any added benefits.

Note that you would have to execute the following command:

```
source "filepath_to_your_profile_path"
```

or restart your terminal for this to take effect.

Comment: Java makes this difficult because the JRE is too stupid to strip the `.class` off the filename, and will fail if you just pass it a file name. You would need to write a function or simple script that strips the extension.

Comment: From what I get from the question though, the user passes the classname and not the file name. Or am I getting the question wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add parameters to the `java` command, that's easy enough:

```
alias java="java -Xmx2g"
```

That would let you run `java <classname>` to launch the class in a JRE instance that is allowed to use up to 2GB of RAM. If you want to make an alternate version of the `java` command that runs with different parameters, that's also easy:

```
alias runjar="java -jar"
```

That would let you run `runjar <jarfilename.jar>` to run a .JAR file. Since it calls `java` internally, it will also expand the alias above (if both of them are defined), so the full resulting command would be `java -Xmx2g -jar <jarfilename.jar>`.

In both cases, you would want to add these lines to your `.profile` and/or `.bashrc` (or equivalent for your preferred shell) scripts, so they are loaded automatically when you open a shell.